# Do I still need to split the js file when there is a cache?

Tags: javascript

Recently, I was thinking about a question. In a front-end project, some js files have been used for strong caching. In this case, do I need to split the js files? What is the reason for dismantling or not dismantling? Thanks~

Comment: you can often use smaller pieces sooner on the first visit. After that, there could be more minor boosts from loading optimization, but you're right, it's usually not as important as cold cache hits.

Answer (score -1):

add `?123` something like this to your js file src, this will invalidate cache